# Get just the date (no time) from UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, datepicker

I am trying to get just the date from UIDatePicker:

```
myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
var selectedDate=myDatePicker.date
println(selectedDate)
```

However, this prints more than the date (it prints 2015-04-09 21:45:13 +0000). How do I get just the date part (without the time)? I also set the date picker Mode property to Date.

Comment: I have the same issue right now. The next question would be, what the time part (21:45:13 in your example) represents?

Answer (score 32):

According to the Apple's documentation `datePicker.mode` should be `date` so you can use `DateFormatter` like so

**Swift 4**

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
let selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
print(selectedDate)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDatePicker.date)
```

You can print `dateString`, assign it to a label, whatever. The format will be

> 04/09/15

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3/4, this will print a string of type Mar 08, 2017

```
   datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
    let selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    print(selectedDate)
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.0 version code is here

```
@IBAction func saveDateAction(_ sender: Any) {

        myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
        let selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: myDatePicker.date)
        print("selectedDate",selectedDate)    
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add my bit in on here after coming across a similar problem. I would follow shades answer for String display of date. Not the from XCode 7 and swift 2 onwards when you use a UIDatePicker set the following to only view dates in the Picker:

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
datePicker.datePickerMode = .Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Date picker date :

```
let date = datePicker.date
let dateConverted = Date.init(year: date.GetYear(), month: date.GetMonth(), day: date.GetDay())
//dateConverted result = 2019-02-27 00:00:00 +0000
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "booking_date == %@", dateConverted as CVarArg)
```

Use this extensions:

```
extension Date {

init(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
    var dc = DateComponents()
    dc.year = year
    dc.month = month
    dc.day = day

    var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
    if let date = calendar.date(from: dc) {
        self.init(timeInterval: 0, since: date)
    } else {
        fatalError("Date component values were invalid.")
    }
}

func GetYear() -> Int {
    let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.components([.day , .month , .year], from: self)
    return components.year!
}

func GetMonth() -> Int {
    let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.components([.day , .month , .year], from: self)
    return components.month!
}

func GetDay() -> Int {
    let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.components([.day , .month , .year], from: self)
    return components.day!
}
}
```